# Notification (FCM) function events

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I'm using Firebase for sending notifications to my app users from the console. Every time I send a notification, I want to store the data in the realtime-database and also I want to log who sent the notification from the console.
So far, the only viable way I found to get the publish notification event is:

```
exports.news2db = functions.pubsub.topic('news').onPublish(event => {
    ...
});
```

However, this only applies when I send a notification to a specific topic. I would like to get an event that is triggered every time ANY notification is sent to the console, not only topics. By this, I mean notifications sent to all app users, to single users, etc.. Is there any way to do that?

The second problem I have is to figure out which user configured and sent the notification to the console so I can log that info. What's the best attempt to do this?

```
admin.auth(). ???
```

Comment: Triggering on console notifications isn't currently a feature of Cloud Functions for Firebase.  However, you could write up a feature request for what you're trying to do.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Ok, thanks.. i submited a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about pubsub events.. they are not for notifications. So yeah, there is no way to get an event when a notification is sent from the console.